# How can I write a function that prints out the filenames and date last modified based on search pattern?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Forgive me if this is something very obvious as I am beginner in bash. I'm trying to write a simple function that takes a search pattern as an input and prints out all the files with names that match the search pattern, along with the size, date, and time when the files were last modified.

I know I can already do this with

```
ls -lh tfp*acf.csv | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8,$9}'
```

which gives

```
190B 24 Jun 21:41 tfp_est_nic20_acf.csv
189B 24 Jun 21:42 tfp_est_nic21_acf.csv
189B 24 Jun 21:43 tfp_est_nic22_acf.csv
190B 24 Jun 21:45 tfp_est_nic23_acf.csv
192B 24 Jun 21:46 tfp_est_nic24_acf.csv
189B 24 Jun 21:47 tfp_est_nic26_acf.csv
188B 24 Jun 21:48 tfp_est_nic27_acf.csv
191B 24 Jun 21:49 tfp_est_nic28_acf.csv
```

(with tfp*acf.csv as an example), but it's a little cumbersome to have to type awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8,$9}' every time. The function I had in mind would be as simple as

```
lsf tfp*acf.csv
```

and give the same output as above. I tried writing functions using find and ls (the output for which I've read should not be parsed). For example, I tried

```
lsf() {

  FILTER="$1"
  find . -name '$FILTER' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt
}
```

and

```
lsf() {

  FILTER="$1"
  ls -lh ${FILTER} | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8,$9}'
}
```

but can't get either one to work properly. I appreciate your help.

Additional info: I'm using bash on OSX

Comment: Is this for a script?

Comment: @TheGirrafish It's for my .bashrc file

Comment: Why don't you create an alias in your .bashrc then?

Comment: @TheGirrafish thanks for your comment. I am. I would like to make the search pattern into a function argument. This is where I am having trouble because either the function doesn't give me an output or it only displays the first output (when the folder contains several files that matches the pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you have already should work

```
lsf() {

  FILTER="$1"
  ls -lh ${FILTER} | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8,$9}'
}
```

probably is the way you are invoking it, use

```
$ lsf 'tfp*acf.csv' #quotes
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks. It works with the quotes. Just to make it even simpler, how can I update this function so that I can use it without the quotes. So `lsf tfp*acf.csv`

Comment: The problem is in what is received by the function as an argument when shell expands the value. Try `echo lsf 'tfp*acf.csv'` and `echo lsf tfp*acf.csv`

Comment: Ok so the latter evaluates the wildcard---that explains why I was getting one output initially before I included the quotes. So are you saying that it's impossible to write this function so that the argument doesn't include any quotes?